# get time from php and update by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, time

I want to get time from server for the first time and then update it by JavaScript every second. This is my code:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myvar = '<?php echo strtotime($now); ?>'
    var hours = myvar.getHours();
    var minutes = "0" + myvar.getMinutes();
    var seconds = "0" + myvar.getSeconds();
    myvar=hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=myvar;
}, 1000);
```

But it has error in the second line. The error is "myvar is not a constructor". So how can I do it?

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Are you aware that `'<?php echo strtotime($now); ?>'` isn't a server call? As it is right now, you're trying to set the same time every second.

Comment: Why would this question be voted down?

Comment: @BeetleJuice because the OP doesn't show or describe the error?

Comment: @vascowhite good point

Comment: @vascowhite please let me complete the question then start criticising. The error is "myvar is not a constructor".

Comment: @shekoufeh I don't think vascowhite was criticizing; he was helping me understand why the downvote.  When we try to help, it's frustrating when someone says "there is an error, help" but doesn't show the error. To be fair, you added the error but well after you posted the question. So most of the people who wanted to help early did not see the error.  Hope you have everything working now.

Comment: @shekoufeh Sorry, I didn't realise it would take you 16 hours to complete the question, most people manage it slightly quicker. My bad. As pointed out previously, I wasn't criticising, just offering an opinion on the downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st problem is that your PHP is echoing an integer and setting `myvar` to that integer.  The integer doesn't have a `getMinutes`, `getHours`... function. Instead, use a`Date` object.

2nd problem is that your function doesn't really advance the time because every iteration, `myvar` is reset to the initial value (the PHP echo is only run once, before the browser downloads the page). What you need is `myvar` to hold the correct time every time.

3rd problem is that you're using `setTimeout` which only runs once. Instead you should be using `setInterval` which will run every second.

The solution is to set a `start` time outside the function, then increment it and use it each round:

```
//PHP will set the start time
var start = <?=time()?>;

setInterval(function(){
    //add 1 second and set myvar to the correct current time
    start++;
    var myvar = new Date(start * 1000);
    ...
},1000);
```

You may have to make a small adjustment, because some time will elapse between when PHP writes the `start` value and when the JavaScript is loaded and run in the browser. This will make the JS time lag a bit behind server time.

[**Live demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/wqq3heez/)

Comment: thanks your answer is true. What if I want to use hour:minute and update time just every minute? I changed start++ to start=start+60 and 1000 to 60000 but it wasn't true

Comment: You're asking a different question now.  I would expect the adjustments you made to work. If they don't, open a new question. Show the new code, the result you get, and explain what you're trying to get.

Comment: FYI for anyone seeing this, the time from JS is always 24hr, to get 12hr you can see this article: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-change-gethours-to-12-hour-format

`const twelvehr = myvar.getHours() % 12 || 12;`

Answer (score 0):

[`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) returns a integer that represents the current time.

You're storing that in a variable, as an string.
Your compiled php file will look something like this:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myvar = '1468845612'
```

`myvar` is just a ordinary string, there. That string doesn't have an `.getHours` function.

replace that `var myvar` line with this:

```
var myvar = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($now); ?>000);
```

Rendered output:

```
    var myvar = new Date(1468845612000);
```

Notice how I added the `000` in there.

`strtotime` returns a timestamp in seconds. JavaScript's `Date` constructor expects a timestamp in milliseconds.

---

That all said, the `setInterval` call is pointless.

The php snippet will run only once, on page load. Then the interval will show the same date every second it's executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .getHours(), .getMinutes() function only with javascript date not with php date. One way you can use is :

```
setInterval(function() {
    var myvar = new Date();
    var hours = myvar.getHours();
    var minutes = "0" + myvar.getMinutes();
    var seconds = "0" + myvar.getSeconds();
    myvar=hours + ':' + minutes.substr(-2) + ':' + seconds.substr(-2);
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=myvar;
}, 1000);
```

if you use php you can't update the time

Comment: As I say a want server time for the first time.